# Buscar Objeto Por data e Id Lambda, Linq, asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, expressões-lambda

Eu tenho classe chamada RequisicaoDeVeiculo, uma classe chamada 
MovimentacaoDeVeiculo e a classe Veiculo.

```
     class RequisicaoDeVeiculo
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public DateTime DataDaSolicitacao { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("Veiculo")]
        public int? IdVeiculo { get; set; }
        public virtual Veiculo Veiculo { get; set; }



        [ForeignKey("Motorista")]
        public int? IdMotorista { get; set; }
        public virtual Motorista Motorista { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Mv")]
        public int? IdMv { get; set; }
        public virtual Mv Mv { get; set; } --> Abreviação de Movimentação de Veículo


        [ForeignKey("Usuario")]
        public int IdUsuario { get; set; }
        public virtual Usuario Usuario { get; set; }

        }


public class MovimentacaoDeVeiculo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataDaChegada { get; set; }
}
```

Estou tentado buscar uma solicitação, da seguinte maneira: Suponhamos que um chegou uma multa para determinado veículo, a multa ta na data xx/xx/xxxx

tenho um método para buscar a solicitação, pela data da solicitação e id do veículo, mas não ta funcionando, estou usando Lambda.
Alguém pode me dar uma dica?

```
public ActionResult BuscarSolicitacaoPordata(DateTime? data, int? Idveiculo)
    {
        RequisicaoDeVeiculo requisicao = new RequisicaoDeVeiculo();
        if (data == null && Idveiculo == null)
        {
            ViewBag.IdVeiculo = new SelectList(db.VeiculoDb, "Id", "Descricao", RequisicaoDeVeiculo.IdVeiculo);
            return View();
        }
        ViewBag.IdVeiculo = new SelectList(db.VeiculoDb, "Id", "Descricao", vrs.IdVeiculo);

        var resultado = db.RequisicaoDeVeiculoDb.FirstOrDefault(v => v.DataEHoraServico >= data && v.MovimentacaoDeVeiculo.DataChegada <= data && v.IdVeiculo == Idveiculo);

        if (resultado == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("BuscarSolicitacaoPordata", "Vr").Mensagem("Nenhum Resultado Encontrado!", "Ops!");
        }

        return View(resultado);
    }
```

Comment: De onde vem a propriedade `DataEHoraServico`? A propriedade `DataChegada` não deveria ser `DataDaChegada`? O que é que está a ser retornado?

Comment: `DataEHoraServico`,vem da classe `RequisicaoDeVeiculo`.Data da chegada, vem da classe `MovimentacaoDeVeiculo`, eu tentei usar de uma forma diferente. assim: `var r = db.VrDb.Where(x => x.DataEHoraServico == data && x.Mv.DataChegada <= data).ToList();` essa linha de código me retorna todas as solicitações cuja a data e do serviço for maior ou igual a data escolhida na view, e que a data da chegada seja menor ou igual a data vinda da view,

Comment: Mas conseguiu resolver o seu problema?

Comment: o problema é o seguinte, vamos supor que um veículo saiu para missão dia o 26/06/2018, e retornou dia 30/06/2018. dai chegou uma multa para esse veículo na data de 28/06/2018. eu estou querendo saber, quem estava dirigindo esse veículo, usando a data da multa, e o Id do veículo.

Comment: Depois de listar todos eu uso essa expressão `var v = r.FirstOrDefault(m => m.IdVeiculo == Idveiculo);`

Comment: Mas então com o seu código já consegue retornar o que pretende, certo?

Comment: Não, quando eu uso `var r = db.VrDb.Where(x => x.DataEHoraServico == data && x.Mv.DataChegada <= data).ToList();` ele não me tras nada. e quando eu uso `var r = db.VrDb.Where(x => x.DataEHoraServico == data || x.Mv.DataChegada <= data).ToList();` ele me tras, mas nem sempre o veículo correto

Comment: Se tem o `IdVericulo` terá que o usar na consulta, caso contrário vai devolver-lhe resultados de outros veículos. A propriedade `DataEHoraServico` tem hora, minuto e segundo?

Comment: Tem sim a data e a hora em que o veículo foi para missão, e a data e a hora que o veículo chegou da missão

Answer (score 0):

Você esqueceu de incluir os dados da Movimentação de Veículo à sua Requisição de Veículo. Além disso, a propriedade DataEHoraServico  não faz parte da classe que você postou. Certifique o nome da DataEHoraServico e tente isso:

```
var resultado = db.RequisicaoDeVeiculoDb.Include("MovimentacaoDeVeiculo").FirstOrDefault(v => v.DataEHoraServico >= data && v.MovimentacaoDeVeiculo.DataChegada <= data && v.IdVeiculo == Idveiculo);
```